# WordPress - add_image_size

Tags: wordpress

I am using WordPress to try and setup some image sizes.

The highest resolution that the site supports is `4K`, so if an image is uploaded that is larger than `3840 x 2160` then I want WordPress to generate a resized version

I have used this...

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
    add_image_size( 'img4k',   3840, 99999999 );
}
```

Is this enough? Does this only generate this new size if the image is larger? What happens if it is smaller?

Comment: It will not create an image, if the file is smaller than the size

Answer (score 0):

I think you can directly use image size from the Settings » Media 
[image]

for more reference https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-prevent-wordpress-from-generating-image-sizes/